# Need help and trick about Javascript updates textbox input text and span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to link and update textbox input text and span text depending on a user selection made from a dropdown box.

The code I wrote so far almost does what I need, but once the page is been refreshed, the span text gets flushed and no longer displayed.

Here are the differents cases I need:

( I've been able to get the 2 first cases properly working with my code below )

```js
<script>
 // Set linked fields according to dropdown selection box
 function update_linked_selection() {
  var ID_selection = $("#ID_list"); 
 
  gpio_name.val("~gpio_name(" + ID_selection.find('option:selected').text() + ")~");
  gpio_type.text("~gpio_type(" + ID_selection.find('option:selected').text() + ")~");

  // Store new fieds into localStorage for next page reload
  localStorage.setItem("local_storage_gpio_name", gpio_name.val());
  localStorage.setItem("local_storage_gpio_type", gpio_type.text()); 

  location.reload(false);
}
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  gpio_name.val(localStorage.getItem("local_storage_gpio_name"));
  gpio_type.text(localStorage.getItem("local_storage_gpio_type"));
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var gpio_name = $("#linked_name");
var gpio_type = $("#linked_type");
</script>
    
Here, the user should pick an ID in the dropdown box in order to compose the entry box value .
That dynamic variable will be expected at server side and a callback will happen when the page refresh is requested.
ie : if user selects ID '1' , then the value becomes ~gpio_name(1)~
<p></p> 
Javascript should update the entry box value according to the choice made from dropdown box selection and also the into the span content.
<p></p> 
Submit button is there if user want to manually change the values and send it to server.
<p></p>

<form method="GET" action="gpio1.htm" id="gpio"> 

    <select name="ID" id="ID_list" onchange="update_linked_selection();">
    <option value="x">Select ID below</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>                                        
    </select>

    <input type="text" maxlength="15" name="name" id="linked_name" size="15" maxlengtd="10"> 
    <span id="linked_type"></span>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
</form>
```

- At page load, the user is invited to select an ID from the dropdown box.

Here I expect to have textbox input text and span text cleared like this:

[image]

- User make his selection in the dropdown box, then textbox input text and span text are updated accordingly :

[image]

***Here things get more tricky for me:***

Once text field is set accordingly by change I need to request a page refresh in order to get the ~variables~ updated from the server side.

At the moment when the page refresh happens, the span text previously displayed has gone and no longer displayed.

**How could I get the spam text still displayed after page refresh ?**

- After that, if the user pick back the very first choice named 'Select ID below' then textbox input text and span text become:

[image]

I would like to avoid so and have all text cleared if the user pick that selection.

In other words, how could i make this first choice : '*Select ID below*' as a ***disabled choice*** ?
Expected result should be like this, as same as the very first page load :

[image]

Comment: 1. do your option values have to be 1, 2, 3 etc? if not then just assign `~gpio_name(value here)'. Or just use an if condition to leave out the first one. 2. Use AJAX to get updated values.

Comment: Yes, option values will always be 1,2,3 ... to 10

Comment: then use `if(ID_list.options[ID_list.selectedIndex].value!='x') {}` btw I don't see ID_selection anywhere in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your page refresh issue, you could use HTML5 `localStorage` to take care of that.

Once text field are set, inside `onchange` or anywhere before requesting a refresh you could store the values of the text input & span into `localStorage` variables.

```
// Store
var gpio_name = "~gpio_name(8)~";
var gpio_type = "~gpio_type(8)~";
localStorage.setItem("gpio_name", gpio_name);
localStorage.setItem("gpio_type", gpio_type);
```

Then on pageload/refresh, you could set the value of the text input and span from the earlier stored `localStorage` variables like so

```
// Retrieve
$('#input-text').val(localStorage.getItem("gpio_name"));
$('#span').html(localStorage.getItem("gpio_type"));
```

Read more about WebStorage [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

**Updated after OP's update:**

In your case, the JQuery should look like:

```
var gpio_name = $("#linked_name");
var gpio_type = $("#linked_type");

// Set linked fields according to dropdown selection box
function update_linked_selection() {
  var ID_selection = $("#ID_list"); 
  gpio_name.val("~gpio_name(" + ID_selection.find('option:selected').text() + ")~");
  gpio_type.text("~gpio_type(" + ID_selection.find('option:selected').text() + ")~");

  // Store new fieds into localStorage for next page reload
  localStorage.setItem("local_storage_gpio_name", gpio_name.val());
  localStorage.setItem("local_storage_gpio_type", gpio_type.text()); 

  location.reload(false);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  gpio_name.val(localStorage.getItem("local_storage_gpio_name"));
  gpio_type.text(localStorage.getItem("local_storage_gpio_type"));
});
```

Comment: I edited my code and tried to follow your advice, but i still can't get the variables contents updated by the script ran at server side.  Did i make someone wrong ?

Comment: Currently your're refreshing the page as soon as the user selects an option from the dropdown.. is this intended ?

Comment: Yes because the refresh is necessary to have some tasks done at server side.

Comment: @LaurentCoulon - I have updated my answer with the code required fixing few things. Let me know if you need precise explanation of few changes.

Comment: You don't need 2 functions for this. You can remove the `refresh_page();` function from the onchange.

Comment: I tried your solution but i'm still not getting expected results. entrybox value is not getting updated and span content neither.   i've updated my initial post with the new code.  source could be find here  :  http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/datetimeform/gpio/gpio1.htm